# TFS - reconstructing lost overwritten code?

Tags: dll, tfs, version-control

I was working on a solution and under the assumption that I had already checked in my changes, I pulled down a new version of the solution and all the changes disappeared.

One of my colleagues suggested that as I often ran it in debug mode that there might be a dll kicking about that I can reverse engineer but dlls all seem to have overwritten too.

This is about 2 weeks worth of work so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't shelve or check in the changes before the overwritten, I'am afraid    you'll not be able to revert the file.

However when you edit the files in local, the changes will be temporarily saved to the TFS temporary diff files in "`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp`". The files all have names like "vctmp38604_939733.cs". You can get the changes from them.

So, you can have a check for the folder, hopefully the diff files still there.

Just a suggestion: please ALWAYS shelve or check in code in time in case missing the changes.

Comment: @Pikapops Have you resolved the issue? it that helpful for you?